# Automatically show text of error in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm using code like

```
EditText.setError("Something went wrong");
```

to show an error on an `EditText`. But only the exclamation mark [image: R.drawable.ic_error] icon is shown, not the text of the error. Clicking on it shows the error text.

How can I have the error text display automatically, without needing to touch the icon first?

Comment: Refer here: http://coderzpassion.com/android-material-design-floating-labels-edittext/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set focus to the EditText so that the user doesn't have to click on it.

```
editText.requestFocus()
```

However, this would still only show one error at a time. I believe this is probably still the best way to go since that's the way the platform implements it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   //  In you layout Xml

     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/layFName"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/edittext_hintcolor"
                      app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_name_registration"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:hint="Hint Text"

                        />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

// In java
 private TextInputLayout mLayFName;
 mLayFName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.layFName);

for set error

 mInputLayoutView.setError(msg);
            EditText.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.red), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);}
```